# How to compile OpenSSL 1.1.1 for Android

Tags: android, openssl

does anyone know or have a script to pre-compile OpenSSL 1.1.1 with Android NDK18 on a Linux machine?
This script: https://github.com/david-hoze/build-openssl-android
does only work for 1.1.0.h with NDK17b, just switching the numbers doesn't work.
BRGDS
Marcus

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Updated for OpenSSL 1.1.1b / Android NDK R19C:

```
#!/bin/sh

ANDROID_NDK=~/android-ndk-r19c
OPENSSL_VERSION=1.1.1b

API_LEVEL=23

BUILD_DIR=/tmp/openssl_android_build
OUT_DIR=/tmp/openssl_android

BUILD_TARGETS="armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64"

if [ ! -d openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION} ]
then
    if [ ! -f openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz ]
    then
        wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz || exit 128
    fi
    tar xzf openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz || exit 128
fi

cd openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION} || exit 128


##### Prepare Files #####
sed -i 's/.*-mandroid.*//' Configurations/15-android.conf
patch -p1 -N <<EOP
--- old/Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl   2018-09-11 14:48:19.000000000 +0200
+++ new/Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl   2018-10-18 09:06:27.282007245 +0200
@@ -43,12 +43,17 @@
      # will return the name from shlib(\$libname) with any SO version number
      # removed.  On some systems, they may therefore return the exact same
      # string.
-     sub shlib {
+     sub shlib_simple {
          my \$lib = shift;
          return () if \$disabled{shared} || \$lib =~ /\\.a$/;
-         return \$unified_info{sharednames}->{\$lib}. \$shlibvariant. '\$(SHLIB_EXT)';
+
+         if (windowsdll()) {
+             return \$lib . '\$(SHLIB_EXT_IMPORT)';
+         }
+         return \$lib .  '\$(SHLIB_EXT_SIMPLE)';
      }
-     sub shlib_simple {
+     
+   sub shlib {
          my \$lib = shift;
          return () if \$disabled{shared} || \$lib =~ /\\.a$/;

EOP

##### remove output-directory #####
rm -rf $OUT_DIR

##### export ndk directory. Required by openssl-build-scripts #####
export ANDROID_NDK

##### build-function #####
build_the_thing() {
    TOOLCHAIN=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
    export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/$TRIBLE/bin:$TOOLCHAIN/bin:"$PATH"
echo $PATH
    make clean
    #./Configure $SSL_TARGET $OPTIONS -fuse-ld="$TOOLCHAIN/$TRIBLE/bin/ld" "-gcc-toolchain $TOOLCHAIN" && \
    ./Configure $SSL_TARGET $OPTIONS -fuse-ld="$TOOLCHAIN/$TRIBLE/bin/ld" && \
    make && \
    make install DESTDIR=$DESTDIR || exit 128
}

##### set variables according to build-tagret #####
for build_target in $BUILD_TARGETS
do
    case $build_target in
    armeabi)
        TRIBLE="arm-linux-androideabi"
        TC_NAME="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
        #OPTIONS="--target=armv5te-linux-androideabi -mthumb -fPIC -latomic -D__ANDROID_API__=$API_LEVEL"
        OPTIONS="--target=armv5te-linux-androideabi -mthumb -fPIC -latomic -D__ANDROID_API__=$API_LEVEL"
        DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/armeabi"
        SSL_TARGET="android-arm"
    ;;
    armeabi-v7a)
        TRIBLE="arm-linux-androideabi"
        TC_NAME="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
        OPTIONS="--target=armv7a-linux-androideabi -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=$API_LEVEL"
        DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/armeabi-v7a"
        SSL_TARGET="android-arm"
    ;;
    x86)
        TRIBLE="i686-linux-android"
        TC_NAME="x86-4.9"
        OPTIONS="-fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=${API_LEVEL}"
        DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/x86"
        SSL_TARGET="android-x86"
    ;;
    x86_64)
        TRIBLE="x86_64-linux-android"
        TC_NAME="x86_64-4.9"
        OPTIONS="-fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=${API_LEVEL}"
        DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/x86_64"
        SSL_TARGET="android-x86_64"
    ;;
    arm64-v8a)
        TRIBLE="aarch64-linux-android"
        TC_NAME="aarch64-linux-android-4.9"
        OPTIONS="-fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=${API_LEVEL}"
        DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/arm64-v8a"
        SSL_TARGET="android-arm64"
    ;;
    esac

    rm -rf $DESTDIR
    build_the_thing
#### copy libraries and includes to output-directory #####
    mkdir -p $OUT_DIR/inc/$build_target
    cp -R $DESTDIR/usr/local/include/* $OUT_DIR/inc/$build_target
    mkdir -p $OUT_DIR/lib/$build_target
    cp -R $DESTDIR/usr/local/lib/*.so $OUT_DIR/lib/$build_target
done

echo Success
```

Comment: Worked FLAWLESSLY! I used ndk r19c, api level 28, openssl 1.1.1c. For MacOS I needed to change 'linux-x86_64' to 'darwin-x86_64'.

Comment: This is awesome I can build libraries but libcrypto throws error failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__register_atfork" referenced by on API 22 (Android 5) on loading

Comment: Perhaps you can try to setting the API Level in the script to 22. But eventually 22 is outdated and incompatible with newer versions.

Comment: This thing fails with 
`ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This works on a Debian Windows Subsystem:

```html
#!/bin/sh

ANDROID_NDK=~/android-ndk-r18b
OPENSSL_VERSION=1.1.1a

API_LEVEL=23

BUILD_DIR=/tmp/openssl_android_build
OUT_DIR=/tmp/openssl_android

BUILD_TARGETS="armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64"

if [ ! -d openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION} ]
then
        if [ ! -f openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz ]
        then
                wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz || exit 128
        fi
        tar xzf openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz || exit 128
fi

cd openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION} || exit 128


##### Prepare Files #####
sed -i 's/.*-mandroid.*//' Configurations/15-android.conf
patch -p1 -N <<EOP
--- old/Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl       2018-09-11 14:48:19.000000000 +0200
+++ new/Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl       2018-10-18 09:06:27.282007245 +0200
@@ -43,12 +43,17 @@
      # will return the name from shlib(\$libname) with any SO version number
      # removed.  On some systems, they may therefore return the exact same
      # string.
-     sub shlib {
+     sub shlib_simple {
          my \$lib = shift;
          return () if \$disabled{shared} || \$lib =~ /\\.a$/;
-         return \$unified_info{sharednames}->{\$lib}. \$shlibvariant. '\$(SHLIB_EXT)';
+
+         if (windowsdll()) {
+             return \$lib . '\$(SHLIB_EXT_IMPORT)';
+         }
+         return \$lib .  '\$(SHLIB_EXT_SIMPLE)';
      }
-     sub shlib_simple {
+
+       sub shlib {
          my \$lib = shift;
          return () if \$disabled{shared} || \$lib =~ /\\.a$/;

EOP

##### remove output-directory #####
rm -rf $OUT_DIR

##### export ndk directory. Required by openssl-build-scripts #####
export ANDROID_NDK

##### build-function #####
build_the_thing() {
        TOOLCHAIN=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/$TC_NAME/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
        export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/$TRIBLE/bin:$TOOLCHAIN/bin:"$PATH"
        make clean
        ./Configure $SSL_TARGET $OPTIONS -fuse-ld="$TOOLCHAIN/$TRIBLE/bin/ld" "-gcc-toolchain $TOOLCHAIN" && \
        make && \
        make install DESTDIR=$DESTDIR || exit 128
}

##### set variables according to build-tagret #####
for build_target in $BUILD_TARGETS
do
        case $build_target in
        armeabi)
                TRIBLE="arm-linux-androideabi"
                TC_NAME="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
                OPTIONS="--target=armv5te-linux-androideabi -mthumb -fPIC -latomic -D__ANDROID_API__=$API_LEVEL"
                DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/armeabi"
                SSL_TARGET="android-arm"
        ;;
        armeabi-v7a)
                TRIBLE="arm-linux-androideabi"
                TC_NAME="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"
                OPTIONS="--target=armv7a-linux-androideabi -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=$API_LEVEL"
                DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/armeabi-v7a"
                SSL_TARGET="android-arm"
        ;;
        x86)
                TRIBLE="i686-linux-android"
                TC_NAME="x86-4.9"
                OPTIONS="-fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=${API_LEVEL}"
                DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/x86"
                SSL_TARGET="android-x86"
        ;;
        x86_64)
                TRIBLE="x86_64-linux-android"
                TC_NAME="x86_64-4.9"
                OPTIONS="-fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=${API_LEVEL}"
                DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/x86_64"
                SSL_TARGET="android-x86_64"
        ;;
        arm64-v8a)
                TRIBLE="aarch64-linux-android"
                TC_NAME="aarch64-linux-android-4.9"
                OPTIONS="-fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=${API_LEVEL}"
                DESTDIR="/tmp/$BUILD_DIR/arm64-v8a"
                SSL_TARGET="android-arm64"
        ;;
        esac

        rm -rf $DESTDIR
        build_the_thing
#### copy libraries and includes to output-directory #####
        mkdir -p $OUT_DIR/inc/$build_target
        cp -R $DESTDIR/usr/local/include/* $OUT_DIR/inc/$build_target
        mkdir -p $OUT_DIR/lib/$build_target
        cp -R $DESTDIR/usr/local/lib/*.so $OUT_DIR/lib/$build_target
done

echo Success
```