# Android - OpenSSL 1.1.1 UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I've been working with OpenSSL version 1.1.1 with Android. Inside my module's CMake I refer to `libssl` as `SHARED` and `IMPORTED` and linking it with module's own library. When  `STATIC` lib  is used compilation throws

> "Undefined reference to stdin, stderr."

For now, I chose dynamic and compiling is OK, but I got following error on runtime as:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libssl.so" not found.

The object is there and has related function definitions.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178805/9805216) for building. Target API level 26 and using NDK version 19.

Maybe I am building with wrong options? compatibility? or should lower target version?

Comment: Please make sure your `.apk` contains `libssl.so` in _each_ directory `/lib/%BUILD_TARGET%` where `BUILD_TARGET` comes from your build script (`BUILD_TARGETS="armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64"`). Make sure your target device supports any of that architectures. Please also post code that loads native library.

Comment: It actually does not show libssl.so and libcrypto.so and I thought maybe it won't cause they are imported and linked to my own library. But, what strange is now my own lib(libsecurity.so) does not show up, so obviously sth is wrong there. Thank you.

Also I do not wrap OpenSSL in JNI format and load them on Java side. I have the function calls in C(security module) and just have the headers and library linking. Would not it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Target API level 26
>
> "Undefined reference to stdin, stderr."

It looks like openssl is built for 26, but your app is built for something pre-23. See the first bullet under https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#using-mismatched-prebuilt-libraries

Your `minSdkVersion` cannot be lower than the maximum `minSdkVersion` of all your dependencies.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libssl.so" not found.

Looks like you didn't include it in your APK?

Comment: It was the versioning. Thank you. Also was getting again "undefined reference inflateInit" and more which related to zLib,   used 'no-comp' within openSSL ./Configure options. 

libssl.so is generated with symbolic link to libssl.so.1.1(which does not exist) after the build script. That's why it can not find. Put dummy file to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717228/how-to-compile-openssl-1-1-1-for-android/55178805#55178805) can build openssl flawlessly.

When you try to integrate the `libssl.so` or `libcrypto.so`, you have to organise your directory structure as below.

**Directory structure**

```
openssl_android/lib/
    ├── arm64-v8a/                       <-- ARM 64bit
    │   └── libssl.so
    ├── armeabi-v7a/                     <-- ARM 32bit
    │   └── libssl.so
    ├── x86_64/                          <-- Intel 64bit
    │   └── libssl.so
    └── x86/                             <-- Intel 32bit
        └── libssl.so
```

**Update your gradle file**

Add below line into your `app/build.gradle` file to let gradle point your `jniLibs` to `openssl`

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs += ['<path-to-openssl>/openssl_android/lib']
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** the path has to be to the level of `openssl_android/lib`, i.e. the parent dir of **ABIs**.

Comment: Thank you. I am building and getting the libs same way.

Comment: The gradle configuration will help you package the library into your apk